# JSF 1.1 to 1.2 migration

Tags: maven-2, jsf

I'm currently using **JSF 1.1** on **Apache Tomcat 6.0.13**, with **maven** 2.

I'm planing to migrate from JSF 1.1 to 1.2. Could someone point me at:
- what JSF implementation is best to use 
- is this implementation available at maven central repository
- what part of code will I need to adjust (I'm using custom tags in my project, but besides that it's all plain JSF)

etc.

Any info would be helpful... Thanx!

**[edit 1]:**

Hm, it haven't worked for me. Dependencies cannot be downloaded from the repository you've specified. Maybe it's because this is link for **maven 1** repository. I'm using following pom settings instead:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

I hope this approach is the correct one. If someone has a more maven-friendly solution, please advise. Thanx!

**[edit 2]:**
After I've changed my JSF jar from 1.1. to 1.2, following error occurred during application startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: 
javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
```

To fix this error, additional listener need to be added in web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following release notes that has a migration guide from 1.1 to 1.2
http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

The maven2 artifacts for JSF 1.2 have found their way in the standard maven2 repository located at http://http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

**JSF Implementation**

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/jsf-impl/1.2-b19/

**JSF API**

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.2-b19/

As such, you shouldn't require any special repository setup in your pom.xml or settings.xml

The dependencies can be defined like this in the pom (1.2-b19 is the latest version at the time of writing) :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-b19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-b19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Included below is a full pom.xml that should contain the basic dependencies for starting a JSF 1.2 project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ecs.sample.jsf</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleJsfPom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-b19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-b19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanx, this is just the info I've been searching for.

Comment: I've put the edit in my question, since it's not possible to format code in comment section...

Comment: Thanx a lot. I've managed to work. Just needed to add 2 listeners in web.xml, and it working fine after this. Listeners are in the updated question.